# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider taking long time for initialization using CGDataProviderDirectCallbacks dataprovider

Tags: ios, pdf, dataprovider, on-the-fly

`CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider` taking long time for initialization using `CGDataProviderDirectCallbacks` data provider.

Here is code snippet:

```
CGDataProviderDirectCallbacks directCallBacks;
directCallBacks.version = 0;
directCallBacks.getBytePointer = NULL;
directCallBacks.releaseBytePointer = NULL;
directCallBacks.releaseInfo = NULL;
directCallBacks.getBytesAtPosition = getBytesAtOffset;


dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateDirect(NULL,fsize,&directCallBacks);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);
```

It immediately starts calling `getBytesAtOffset` in while initializing using `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider` which is not expected. (It should not start scanning pdf immediately).
results in taking long time to complete this `CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);` 
Please suggest me if I am doing it wrongly.